# Rita word net does not consider space in a word

Tags: java, wordnet

I downloaded Rita word net jar file and i use it in java. but i have a problem.
for example when the string is "absolute coding" and part of speech is "noun", it ignores the second word which is "coding" and returns antonyms or synonyms of "absolute".

why Rita word net ignores the second word(after space)?
thanks in advance

Comment: A "word" does not contain spaces. "Absolute coding" is not a word, nor a noun; it is a noun phrase containing the adjective "absolute" as a specifier for the noun (or, well, gerund) "coding". What sort of synonyms or antonyms would you expect to obtain for this phrase?

Comment: you are right. "absolute coding" is a phrase. But for example if a word is "put on" and we want to get antonyms, Rita word net get "off" as synonym. i mean the words which have a space, the antonyms and synonyms are not true.my another question is why when the word is "be" and we get examples, one of the example is "What is behind this behavior?"

Comment: Are you using the current RiTa (which now contains the WordNet package) or the older RiTa.Wordnet? Why version# do you see?